# How to store and access values outside loop in jinja

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have seen few Questions asking same , but I could not figure out how to

I have a for loop as:

```
{% for brands in data %}
   {{ brands['brand'] }} // 'test1','test2'..... 
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to access the `brands['brand']` values outside of loop , I am doing as:

```
{% set newlist = [] %}
{% for brands in data %}
   {% set newlist = newlist.append(brands['brand']) %}
   {{ brands['brand'] }} // 'test1','test2'..... 
{% endfor %}
```

now when I access newlist as `{{ newlist }}` after loop it gives me result

But, May I know how can i access the newlist above declaration ? (sorry if this doesn't make any sense)

Any help is appreciated ...TIA

Comment: Can you update your question with how `data` data-structure looks like ?

Comment: I think your code is working fine. Your data might be empty

Comment: Its working as you said , i have edited Q please could you look into that

Answer (score 0):

Please change this piece of code :

```
{% set newlist = newlist.append(brands['brand']) %}
```

to this :

```
{% set newlist = newlist.append( {{ brands['brand'] }} ) %}
```

Comment: sorry , this gives me exception as jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'